# Form Select not rendering as a dropdown

Tags: 8, forms

I'm building a form that contains a `select` but it's not rendering as a dropdown. It's rendering with a scrollbar and a dropdown down arrow

[image]

```
$form['my_select'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#empty_option' => '- None -',
  '#title' => $this->t('My Select'),
  '#options' => ['Option1', 'Option2'],
  '#size' => 6,
  '#weight' => '0',
];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you switch to the default, Bartik theme, does it look how you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's rendering as a list because you have set `#size` to 6, which means 6 rows will be visible. Either remove the `#size` property completely, or set it to 1 to display a normal dropdown.

From the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Select.php/class/Select/8.8.x):

> #size: The number of rows in the list that should be visible at one time.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!